# Elm record updating mismatch with type alias

Tags: record, elm

I have the following type:

```
type alias SelList a =
    { list : List a
    , selected : Maybe a
    }
```

A `Sel(ectable)List a` is a list of `a` from which I can possibly choose an element.

In my application, all my objects have an `id : Int` field, so I've defined this type alias :

```
type alias HasId r = { r | id : Int}
```

Now I would like a function eventually selecting an element in the list, I've tried :

```
select : Int -> SelList (HasId r)-> Maybe (SelList (HasId r))
select id sl = find (\x-> x.id ==id) sl.list &> \ el ->
               Just { sl | selected = el }
```

where `(&>) = flip Maybe.andThen` and `find : (a ->  Bool) -> List a -> Maybe a`.

I've got the following message:

```
The type annotation for `select` says it always returns:

    Maybe (SelList (HasId r))

But the returned value (shown above) is a:

    Maybe { list : List (HasId r), selected : { r | id : Int } }
```

I'm confused because `{ r | id : Int }` is the same than `HasId`, and then

```
{ list : List (HasId r), selected : HasId r }
```

is the same than `SelList (HasId r)`. Why the compiler can not figure out that the types match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler's error is 90% of the way there, but I think mixing type aliases and records makes it harder to figure out what's wrong. (Future versions of Elm are going to improve this).

If it was a record and not a `Maybe record`, the compiler would tell you something like "I see a problem with the `selected` field`". Does that help?

Spoiler: The `SelList` type has a `selected : Maybe a`, but `select` returns `selected : a`